# Rewrite parts of links using Greasemonkey and FireFox

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

A friend of mine uploaded about 20 or so galleries of nature shots she's done over the past year or so onto webshots.com, however, I just purchased a paid Flickr account for her as a birthday gift, and I want to download all of her photos from webshots and have them ready for her to upload to Flickr once she gets the email about her account upgrade (she's out of the country - no internet access.)

I don't have access to her webshots account, so I've resorted to Greasemonkey and DownThemAll to start saving her images into folders on my desktop.

I'm somewhat new to javascript, and all the "user scripts" available for Greasemonkey don't exactly do what I need.

*When a gallery page is loaded:*

```
(http://[category].webshots.com/album/[album-id]),
```

*I need the Greasemonkey script to find all links to images:*

```
(http://[category].webshots.com/photo/[photo-page-id])
```

*and re-write them to reflect this scheme:*

```
(http://community.webshots.com/photo/fullsize/[photo-page-id])
```

Is this easy to do? It seems like it would be, but I can't seem to get it right.

**Here's my current Greasemonkey script that doesn't work:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Webshot Gallery Fixer
// @namespace      WGF
// @description    Fixes webshot galleries
// @include        http://*.webshots.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); //array
var regex = /^(http:\/\/)([^\.]+)(\.webshots\.com\/photo\/)(.+)$/i;
for (var i=0,imax=links.length; i<imax; i++) {
   links[i].href = liks[i].href.replace(regex,"$1community$3fullsize/$4");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but it seems that doing it by hand may actually be faster than writing code do it for you.

Comment: You should make a note when you copy code from one of the answers and edit it into your question. Otherwise it gets confusing. In this case you copied a typo when you copied my answer. As @Brock Adams points out, you can just fix the typo and it should work for you.

Answer (score 6):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); //array
var regex = /^(http:\/\/)([^\.]+)(\.webshots\.com\/photo\/)(.+)$/i;
for (var i=0,imax=links.length; i<imax; i++) {
   links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(regex,"$1community$3fullsize/$4");
}
```

ought to do the trick

Comment: @Brock Adams Probably because the OP lifted that code from the answer.  Check the edits on the question.

Comment: @George Marian:  Yeah, it looks that way when checking edit histories.  Sorry about that, Robusto, still have that typo, though. ;-)

Comment: @Robusto I did no such thing, @Brock Adams deserves the credit for pointing out the typo. :)

Comment: @Brock Adams: Sorry for the mix-up.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was fine but for a typo:

`links[i].href =` **liks[i]** `.href.replace(regex,"$1community$3fullsize/$4");`

Replace ***liks*** with ***links*** and it works.

Open up the Firebug console, turn most of the warnings on, and reload the page.  You can see errors your script might cause (plus a metric ton of errors from the site itself).

Comment: +1 for spotting the typo, though you typo'd yourself.  It's liks. ;)

Comment: @George Marian:  D'Oh!  That's what I get for trying to recreate the error, by hand, from my fixed copy of the code.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late answer, but I'll post anyway in case it'll do some good.

I'm kind of newb to this stuff myself, but I don't think it will help to assign a value to links[i].href since it's just a variable. You won't change anything on the page by doing so. I think you should replace this:

```
links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(regex,"$1community$3fullsize/$4");
```

with this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href = links[i].href.replace(regex,"$1community$3fullsize/$4");
```