# How can i make my browser automatically change a website's URL?

Tags: url, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

is there a way to automatically transform every URL from this news site:

haaretz.co.il

that has the word "premium" in it, like so:

haaretz.co.il/news/world/america/.premium-1.2061777

to this format:

haaretz.co.il/mobile/opinions/.premium-1.2061777

i am using firefox 22.0

can i make this an add-on for firefox? it would be useful for a lot of people.
something that people can easily replicate and use would be good.

to sum up:

somthing that edits a url of choice:

"www.example.com/catagory/something.12345"

by taking a user selected part:

"something.12345"

and inserts it in the user's url of choice:

"www.example.com/{part inserted here}" or even "www.example.com/{part inserted here}/catagory"

i have little programing experiance and even less experiance programing for web.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to write new add-on.  You can use the [GreaseMonkey plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for firefox and write some small javascript to tell GreaseMonkey to remap your URL.   This SO post sounds very similar to what you need to do: [Rewrite parts of a URL in Greasemonkey and FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232992/rewrite-parts-of-a-url-in-greasemonkey-and-firefox)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).