# Replace parts of a URL in Greasemonkey

Tags: regex, greasemonkey

I'm trying to replace a part of url using a Greasemonkey script, but having hard time to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Original Urls are like:

```
http://x1.example.to/images/thumb/50/157/1571552600.jpg
http://x2.example.to/images/thumb/50/120/1201859695.jpg
http://x3.example.to/images/thumb/50/210/2109983330.jpg
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
http://example.to/images/full/50/157/1571552600.jpg
http://example.to/images/full/50/120/1201859695.jpg
http://example.to/images/full/50/210/2109983330.jpg
```

I just want to replace **thumb** with **full** and cut out the **x1**.example.to, **x2**.example.to, **x3**.example.to, **x4**.example.to etc.. part completely from the original URL so new urls will be starting like `example.to/images/full/`

How do I achieve this?

I have found a Greasemonkey script from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232992/rewrite-parts-of-a-url-in-greasemonkey-and-firefox) and did try to work out but failed.

Here's what i did so far.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Example Images Fixer
// @namespace      Example
// @description    Fixes image galleries
// @include        http://*.example.to/*
// ==/UserScript==

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); //array
var regex = /^(http:\/\/)([^\.]+)(\.example\.to\/images\/thumb/\)(.+)$/i;
for (var i=0,imax=links.length; i<imax; i++) {
   links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(regex,"$4full/$5");
}
```

Any help on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're forgetting to put the `http://` part in your replacement URL:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)[^.]+\.(example\.to\/images\/)thumb\/(.+)$/i
```

and then:

```
.replace(regex, "$1$2full/$3");
```

You can see the results [here](http://regex101.com/r/aS1bJ8/1).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what can be done:

```
var urls = ['http://x1.example.to/images/thumb/50/157/1571552600.jpg',
'http://x2.example.to/images/thumb/50/120/1201859695.jpg',
'http://x3.example.to/images/thumb/50/210/2109983330.jpg'];


for (var i = 0, len = urls.length; i < len; i++) {

    urls[i] = 
      urls[i].replace(/:\/\/[^\.]+\.(example.to\/images\/)thumb/, '://$1full');
    console.log(urls[i]);

}

/* result
"http://example.to/images/full/50/157/1571552600.jpg"
"http://example.to/images/full/50/120/1201859695.jpg"
"http://example.to/images/full/50/210/2109983330.jpg"
*/
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xaXM/1/)