# How can I replace a segment of the URL and reload the page?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, greasemonkey

I need to write a script for Greasemonkey that will check the URL, replace a section of it when certain conditions are met, and reload the page.

The URLs in question will always be in this format:

https://optionA.example.com/ab/first/second/tonsOfMetadata

https://optionB.example.com/ab/first/second/tonsOfMetadata

I need the script to check for the "first/second" segment and then replace it with "third/fourth." These will always be the same. The only thing that will change from URL to URL is the metadata and the subdomain which will either be A or B.

This is the code I'm trying to get working:

```
var url = window.location.host; 
var regex = /^(https?:\/\/)([^.]+\.)(example\.com\/ab\/)first\/second(\/.+)$/i;

if (url.match(regex) != null){
url = window.location.href;
url = url.replace(regex,"$1$2$3third/fourth$4");
    return;
}

console.log(url);
window.location.replace(url);
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but my experience with coding is limited. I've adapted the code from here: [Replace parts of a URL in Greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984576/replace-parts-of-a-url-in-greasemonkey) and from here: [Rewrite parts of a URL in Greasemonkey and FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232992/rewrite-parts-of-a-url-in-greasemonkey-and-firefox).

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you just need this:

```
var url = window.location.host; 
var regex = /^(https?:\/\/)([^.]+\.)(example\.com\/ab\/)first\/second(\/.+)$/i;

if (url.match(regex) != null) {
    url = window.location.href;
    url = url.replace(regex,"$1$2$3third/fourth$4");
}
console.log(url);
window.location.href = url;
```

Instead of your call to a replace method (I don't think, it exists). Also your "return" statement is superfluous/wrong, as it seems.

Comment: So, I just need to switch the 5th line from "url = window.location.href;" to "window.location.href = url;" and remove "return;" and it should work?

Comment: No. I meant, that you need to remove the return (since it makes no sense, as much I could see) and to replace "window.location.replace(url);" by "window.location.href = url;" --- see my update!

Comment: Thanks for the update! I tried this code and the script is recognizing the URL, but the page just keeps reloading. Somewhere it's getting stuck instead of replacing the segment of the URL. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds, as your replace is not working. What is printed on console? Of course, when your URL is not changed, the statement "window.location.href = url;" will reload the current page every time. So make sure, that it is only done, when a replace has really taken place. You should place the two last lines inside the if, but you also should check the result of replace.