# Use Greasemonkey to change URL links within a given domain

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm new to Greasemonkey (Tampermonkey actually), and I'd like to write a very short script that:

- Is valid within a given domain (e.g. "mydomain.com")
- Parses all button-related URL links within the active tab
- Replaces them as follows :

  Original URL link: `[string_1]/[useful_part]?[string_2]`

  To be replaced with: `[replacement_1]/[useful_part]`

  So everything after the "?" can be discarded, including the "?" itself.

More specifically, URL links are as follows:

[http://127.0.0.1:6878/webui/player/[useful_part]?autoplay=true](http://127.0.0.1:6878/webui/player/%5Buseful_part%5D?autoplay=true)

So string 1 = "http://127.0.0.1:6878/webui/player" and string 2 = "autoplay=true"

I've seen a similar question here: [Rewrite parts of links using Greasemonkey and FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232992/rewrite-parts-of-links-using-greasemonkey-and-firefox)

But I'm not good enough at RegEx, so I couldn't adapt the script to my own needs.

I've also looked for Firefox extensions, but the available extensions don't seem to allow the level of text replacement that I'm seeking.

Comment: You will be much more likely to get answers to your question if you include what you have tried. See how to create a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have included what I've tried. The rest is under cssyphus' reply, since that is the code that I'm currently trying.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the working script thanks to cssyphus. {DOMAIN_NAME} needs of course to be replaced:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Webui Player Replacements
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @description  Change URL links to AceStream on a given domain
// @version      0.1
// @match        http://{DOMAIN_NAME}/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    const lnks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    lnks.forEach( (el) => {
        const href = el.getAttribute('href');
        const ed1 = href.split('?')[0];
        const ed2 = ed1.replace('http://127.0.0.1:6878/webui/player/','');
        el.setAttribute('href', `acestream://${ed2}`);
        el.setAttribute('onclick', `event.preventDefault();window.open('acestream://${ed2}')`);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Downvoting this answer. It is very bad form indeed to take code someone else wrote to solve your problem, and then post that code (almost verbatim!) and choose yours as the Best Answer. That is directly opposite to the intentions of the StackOverflow community - and is why you did not receive any points at all for that Best Answer. All you did was to rob the actual answer provider of their deserved points. I urge you to delete this answer and select a new Best Answer from among those provided. I will monitor this answer and will report the question to the senior moderator if not addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that button elements do not have links - they are probably "a" tags.  If the below script is not correct, let us know what is not correct about it and provide detailed information (perhaps a screenshot of one of the button links?) and we'll fix this answer to work.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         your webui player replacements
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        http://127.0.0.1:6878/webui/player/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    const lnks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    lnks.forEach( (el) => {
        const href = el.getAttribute('href');
        const ed1 = href.split('?')[0];
        const ed2 = ed1.replace('http://127.0.0.1:6878/webui/player','');
        el.setAttribute('href', `replacement_string/${ed2}`;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much cssyphus.
I think there's a missing ")" in the penultimate line, so I've added it.
But there's another parsing error in the last line (unexpected token), which I don't understand. Once this is sorted out, I'll be able to test the script and report back.

Comment: I guess I found out the remaining error: the last line needs to be repeated once (so typed two times in total). I'll test the script later today, and hopefully I'll report back within 24h.

Comment: First feedback: so far it doesn't work. The script is active on the intended domain as it should, but the URL links aren't affected at all.

Comment: Yeah, sorry Jose, I just wanged out that code off the top of my head without testing anything (nothing to test with <grin>). If it is not working, then I need to see the underlying page HTML - perhaps you can open DevTools (F12) and screenshot some of those links. Then I will know for sure how to target them.

Comment: No problem, thanks for willing to help. For the record, these are all live TV streaming links. Currently they open in a web player, and what I want to do is to open them with an external player, which can be achieved by modifying the links (Firefox will then recognize the links and open them in an external player).

Comment: Here's some HTML I found (just an example but all links are similar) : <a onclick="show_webplayer('acestream', '458a0ddd7d193f6d2750cd14d03a47f47a808e09', 120146068, 2085945, 28, 1, 'en'); return false;" href="//cdn.livetv639.me/webplayer2.php?t=acestream&amp;c=458a0ddd7d193f6d2750cd14d03a47f47a808e09&amp;lang=en&amp;eid=120146068&amp;lid=2085945&amp;ci=28&amp;si=1"><img alt="Play" src="//cdn.livetv639.me/img/play.gif" width="23"></a>

Comment: Also, that's the HTML code. The URL link that appears when I hover over the button is slightly different : http://127.0.0.1:6878/webui/player/458a0ddd7d193f6d2750cd14d03a47f47a808e09?autoplay=true

Comment: Hate to say, but I don't think you can do much with that. The `onclick` is doing something important - possibly translating an ID code into an actual web link. AceStream is a P2P streaming service... the `c=` param being sent to the PHP app is the same link that you are extracting from the href... What are the `eid` and `lid` params for? Here's how to solve: if you can figure out how the code you pasted above gets turned into something playable **(a string you paste into the browser address bar -- you need to figure out that string),** then we can automate that for all links on the page.

Comment: Oh but I have already figured that out! The string simply needs to be this: "acestream://[useful part], where the [useful part] string is the series of numbers after the "c=". That automatically launches the relevant external app, because my browser is already configured to do so. It used to work previously. My problem is recent and comes from the fact that the website link URLs, which used to be in the "acestream://" form, now have changed so they open inside a webplayer of their own. I don't want a webplayer. I want an external app, just like before. That's the whole point of my request. :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating another answer so can compare between...

Try this and let me know what happens...  (the first `el.setAttribute` might not be required, or it might...? Try it with, first.)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         your webui player replacements
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        http://127.0.0.1:6878/webui/player/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    const lnks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    lnks.forEach( (el) => {
        const href = el.getAttribute('href');
        const ed1 = href.split('?')[0];
        const ed2 = ed1.replace('http://127.0.0.1:6878/webui/player','');
        el.setAttribute('href', `acestream://${ed2}`;
        el.setAttribute('onclick', `event.preventDefault();window.open('acestream://${ed2}')`;
    });

})();
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI there were two missing ")", one in each el.setAttribute line ;) Also, a question : shouldn't the @match line reflect the website URL instead of my own computer ?

Comment: I'll try the new script and report back. For that first I need to catch a live acestream stream, which doesn't happen all the time. But I'll be back soon.

Comment: Great news! The new script works as intended! It needed a couple of small corrections but it works fine now. I'm going to post the working script as answer to my question. Only a small detail to perfect it: when clicking on a modified AceStream link, Firefox now opens a new, empty tab before launching the AceStream app. Can we prevent this empty tab from being open? It's not really a worry, just asking just in case.

Comment: Try the above edit to the above example. Please upvote if answer found helpful. _Meilleurs voeux!_

Comment: Thanks again :) You may not have noticed, but I already added your script as answer to my question, with the corrections I needed to make for it to work (since I couldn't edit your own post). I'll add your new corrections. Keep in mind that your code doesn't work as is because of two missing parenthesis. Which is why I added the corrected code as answer, giving you credit for it of course. :)

Comment: I am very pleased it is working for you Jose. Keep using TamperMonkey, and check out any scripts you might find useful [here](https://github.com/cssyphus/TamperMonkeyUserscripts) and [here](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts).