# Execute a given Windows command line when clicking on a given link

Tags: javascript, windows, command-line-interface, uri, tampermonkey

This is a follow-up to this question: [Use Greasemonkey to change URL links within a given domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75777790/use-greasemonkey-to-change-url-links-within-a-given-domain/75837435#75837435)

Reminder: I'm using Windows. This is important.

Thanks to the previous script (see below), we now have a web page that displays clickable links in the correct form which is `acestream://{data}`

I'd like to open these links directly into MPV, which is already preconfigured to play them (using this lua script, if anybody's interested: https://github.com/Digitalone1/mpv-acestream ).

For that, I just need to pass the following command line to MPV (already tried, works manually):

```
mpv --profile=acestream acestream://{data}
```

Which is the same as:

```
mpv --profile=acestream {link URL}
```

Could you help me modify the TamperMonkey script to achieve that? Clicking the link would execute such Windows command line without me having to open a Windows command prompt and type everything.

Here's the current state of the script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Webui Player Replacements
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @description  Change URL links to AceStream on a given domain
// @version      0.1
// @match        http://{DOMAIN_NAME}/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    const lnks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    lnks.forEach( (el) => {
        const href = el.getAttribute('href');
        const ed1 = href.split('?')[0];
        const ed2 = ed1.replace('http://127.0.0.1:6878/webui/player/','');
        el.setAttribute('href', `acestream://${ed2}`);
        el.setAttribute('onclick', `event.preventDefault();window.open('acestream://${ed2}')`);
    });
})();
```

BTW the current script unnecessarily opens an empty new browser tab whenever I click on a link. If there's a way to prevent that from happening, then perfect. If not, I can definitely live with that. Thanks!

Comment: Umm.. why do you need *both* the `el.setAttribute('onclick', ...);` and `el.setAttribute('href', ...);` lines? How is the userscript supposed to run a command in a cmd?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know. If you follow the first link in my OP you'll see that the script was suggested and refined by cssyphys, whom I really thank of course. I'm still a newbie with TamperMonkey. I also don't know whether a TamperMonkey script can run a cmd or not. A browser can run external apps (for example clicking on an Acestream link would launch Acestream player), but maybe a script can't do that directly. I'm willing to learn what is possible and what is not. Oh, and that version of the script isn't supposed to run a cmd, that bit of code remains to be added if possible.

Comment: I hope somebody can end up answering this. Still hoping here. Thank you all!

Comment: Here's an idea: TamperMonkey can't execute a cmd, BUT TamperMonkey could reach a local Python server that would execute the cmd. I have found an article on that, but I could only read the intro since it was a paying article. So yeah, all it would take would be a local Python server (active all the time) and a TamperMonkey call to that server. Could somebody help me with that?